# Plot two groups with count line

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I would like to overlay a line ("n" in the code below) showing the number for each "Analyte", but I get an error that I need a separate value for each "Type". But they are matching pairs, so I only want the total number of pairs for each Analyte. Ideally, with a different Y-axis on the right hand side of the plot.

Any ideas?

```
y1 <- rnorm(10)+5
y2 <- y1+rnorm(10)/2
x <- data.frame("x1",y1,letters[1:10])
names(x) <- c("Type","Value","Analyte")
y <- data.frame("x2",y2, letters[1:10])
names(y) <- c("Type","Value","Analyte")
main <- rbind(x,y)

#Number of pairs per group
n <- round((rnorm(10)+10)*5)

ggplot(main,aes(x=Analyte,y=Value,fill=Type)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position=position_dodge())
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `geom_line(aes(group = 1), stat = "summary", fun = "sum")`

Comment: How would I do that with the variable n?

Comment: Create a separate dataset for the line, e.g. do `geom_line(data = data.frame(Analyte = letters[1:10], Value = n), aes(fill = NULL, group = 1))`

Comment: That worked great. The only thing left is to adjust the axis and add it to the right side. Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Okay, I have it figured out: +
  geom_line(data = data.frame(Analyte = letters[1:10], Value = n/10), aes(fill = NULL, group = 1))+
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10))

Answer (score 0):

```
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',position=position_dodge())+ geom_line(data = 
  data.frame(Analyte = letters[1:10], Value = n/10), aes(fill = NULL, group = 1))+ 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*10))
```